# How to get data from SOAP using PHP

Tags: php, soap

I have this page: http://mncmeorne.no-ip.org/NowPlaying.asmx?op=GetNowPlaying

I need to get the data of the first "ARTIST" and "TITLE" tags:

```
<Artist>string</Artist>
<Title>string</Title>
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you show your attempts to achieve what you want?

Comment: I can't get it yet. I was looking for some ways to get the data here on stackoverflow, on the web... but nothing was helpfull for me to understand how could I get the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've completely revised my earlier answer, because I didn't realize you could not get back real data from the web service. You can access it with a SOAP client. Optional parameters can be passed to the client function, like this:

```
$client->GetNowPlaying(array('foo'=>'bar'))
```

...but, I don't really know what this web service is for and I couldn't figure out any parameter to send. Anyway, the following gets a response:

```
// service description http://mncmeorne.no-ip.org/NowPlaying.asmx?WSDL

// send request
$client = new SoapClient("http://mncmeorne.no-ip.org/NowPlaying.asmx?WSDL");
$result = $client->GetNowPlaying();

// get array of items
$arr = $result->GetNowPlayingResult->PlayerItem;

// iterate and access the artist property of the item
foreach ($arr as $i) {
    echo $i->Artist . "\n";
}

// examine what the SOAP response contains
echo var_dump($client);
echo var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
echo var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Ok, but... How can I get the real data directly from the soap file? The data is changing every 3 minutes, more or less.

Comment: @user3746625 I revised my answer, take another look...